# How can I compute probability of $X$ with a hyperbolic distribution?

Tags: r, probability, distributions

I'm modelling some Spread data in R Statistics and would like to understand how I can compute the $P ≥ 0.000$ from my data set.

I have run a `lik.ratio.test` from the ghyp package and matched `hyp` or  density to my distribution.

The parameters are as follows;

```
  model symmetric    lambda  alpha.bar            mu        sigma
1  ghyp     FALSE -2.521284 0.01780878 0.00001747584 0.0006763044
3   NIG     FALSE -0.500000 1.31394479 0.00002084498 0.0006730642
2   hyp     FALSE  1.000000 1.17555118 0.00002363080 0.0006676542
           gamma      aic     llh converged n.iter
1 -0.00001556858 -2029465 1014738      TRUE    628
3 -0.00001877994 -2028209 1014109      TRUE    245
2 -0.00002163760 -2027239 1013624      TRUE    249
```

The density is as follows;

```
Call:
    density.default(x = E)

Data: E (171243 obs.);  Bandwidth 'bw' = 4.825e-05

       x                   y           
 Min.   :-0.011945   Min.   :  0.0000  
 1st Qu.:-0.005497   1st Qu.:  0.0012  
 Median : 0.000950   Median :  0.0626  
 Mean   : 0.000950   Mean   : 38.7341  
 3rd Qu.: 0.007397   3rd Qu.:  1.2891  
 Max.   : 0.013845   Max.   :742.8313
```

The sd is as follows;

```
> sd(E)
[1] 0.0006900069
```

There are functions in R that allow a $F(x) = P(X <= x)$ such as `pnrom(x, mean, sd)` however I can't seem to find one for a hyperbolic or generalized hyperbolic distribution.

I'm unsure of the math behind the construction of the parameters and their relationship to how I can compute the probability of my data set. Could anyone give me a tip to how I could compute $P ≥ 0.000$ from this data set?

I would provide the data set however there are 171,243 rows (est) on this run through.

```
# Fitting
ef <- (density(E))
ghdfit <- fit.ghypuv(E,symmetric = FALSE, control = list(maxit = 1000))
hypfit <- fit.hypuv(E,symmetric = FALSE, control = list(maxit = 1000))
nigfit <- fit.NIGuv(E,symmetric = FALSE, control = list(maxit = 1000))

# Density
ghddens <- dghyp(ef$x, ghdfit)
 hypdens <- dghyp(ef$x, hypfit)
nigdens <- dghyp(ef$x, nigfit)
 nordens <- dnorm(ef$x, mean = mean(E),sd = sd(c(E[,1])))
col.def <- c("black","red","green","orange")
plot(ef, xlab = " Spread ", ylab = expression(f(x)),ylim = c(0,800), main ='CABLE - 3 Day Comparison across 28 Years')
lines(ef$x, ghddens, col = "red")
 lines(ef$x, hypdens, col = "blue")
lines(ef$x, nigdens, col = "green")
 lines(ef$x, nordens, col = "orange")
```

Here is the comparison;
[image: Comparison]

Here is the result of the `lik.ratio.test`;

```
# Diagnostic
options(scipen=999)
AIC <- stepAIC.ghyp(E, dist = c("ghyp","hyp","NIG"), symmetric = FALSE, control = list(maxit=1000))
LRghdnig <- lik.ratio.test(ghdfit,nigfit)
LRghdhyp <- lik.ratio.test(ghdfit,hypfit)

`> LRghdnig
$statistic
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         L 
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006354298 

$p.value
[1] 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001428244

$df
[1] 1

$H0
[1] FALSE`
```

And Hyperbolic;

```
> LRghdhyp
$statistic
L 
0 

$p.value
[1] 0

$df
[1] 1

$H0
[1] FALSE
```

**Data:** is currency USD/GBP (Cable) over 28 years. The data being modeled is the spread of the Open and Close prices at particular intervals.

**Goals:** To calculate the probability from the dataset of a 0.0001 spread and -0.0001 spread occurring.

**Problem:** How do I do this with a hyperbolic or generalized hyperbolic distribution?

Comment: This is pretty sparse, can you add some context? Can you say more about your situation, your data, & your goals? I'm not sure if this can be answered in its present state.

Comment: Sure, I'll make some adjustments, thank you for your comment gung.

Comment: @gung - Does this help a bit more, thanks for your time.

Comment: What's wrong with the `pghyp` function in the `ghyp` package?

Comment: Isn't there a difference between hyperbolic and g.hyperbolic, I say this as I believe hyperbolic is a better fit. For this reason, I have looked into a similar function for a hyperbolic dist, and cannot find anything. In regards to the [link]http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ghyp/docs/pghyp `pghyp(q, object = ghyp(), n.sim = 10000, subdivisions = 200,
      rel.tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5, abs.tol = rel.tol,
      lower.tail = TRUE)`
I don't understand how to use the function i.e. which quantiles, what ghyp object. This would be handy to know as well. @fg nu

Comment: Note the sentence "...for the univariate and multivariate generalized hyperbolic distribution and **its special cases**.", and the second argument, `object` where you are passing a `gyhp` object which could be a hyperbolic, NIG, ...

Comment: Please consider posting your data to Github gists for a complete answer.

Comment: @fg nu - I'm not familiar with Github. My email is william.e.junger@gmail.com, pop me an email and I'll email the csv over? (let me know when you've emailed)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20716/discussion-between-willj-and-fg-nu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP sent me his data over email. Here is how to compute the CDF of a Hyperbolic distribution using the `gyhp` package:

```
# read in the data
dfX = read.csv("Data//5MinSpread.csv")

# fit a Hyperbolic distribution model to the data
hypSS = fit.hypuv(dfX$SS.1)

# P[SS <= 0]
pghyp(q = 0, object = hypSS)
```